# Espressione formale per "qualcosa in contrario"

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

Mi potete suggerire qualche alternativa formale ad una frase del tipo:

> Fatemi sapere se avete qualcosa in contrario.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Io suggerirei:

> Fatemi sapere se avete obiezioni in merito

Comment: Perfetto, grazie!

Comment: Non c'è di che.

Comment: Anche senza “in merito”.